# Stop HTML table "shunting" (page-break?) into next page when converted to PDF

Tags: html, css, weasyprint

I have a HTML page with CSS and I convert it to PDF. My HTML page contains a table which when small renders directly under the header at the top of the page but when the table is big, it is shunted (i.e. page break) down and starts at the 2nd page. It spills over into the 3rd page correctly - but how do i stop this page break on page 1? I've tried adding `page-break-inside`, `page-break-before` and `page-break-after` to the @page and table styles but it doesn't work.

I.e. this is happening:
[image]

The desired behaviour is as it is when the table is small, i.e.:
[image]

The code is:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            @page {
                margin: 0.2cm;
            }
            body {
                font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
                font-size: 12px;
                line-height: 1.25rem;
            }
            h1 {
                line-height: 2rem;
            }
            img {
                display: block;
                float: right;
                height: 120px;
                margin-bottom: 0.25rem;
                object-fit: cover;
                width: 192px;
            }
            table {
                border-collapse: collapse;
                table-layout: fixed;
                width: 100%
            }
            table, td, th {
                border: 0.1rem solid black;
            }
            td {
                overflow: hidden;
                overflow-wrap: break-word;
                padding: 0.2rem;
                vertical-align: top;
            }
            th {
                padding: 0.1rem 0.2rem;
                font-size: 0.75rem;
                text-decoration: underline;
            }
            tr.compact td {
                padding: 0.05rem 0.2rem;
                line-height: 1rem;
            }
            tr.spacer td {
                background-color: lightgrey;
                height: 0.2rem;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <title>Shopping Lists</title>
    <body>
        <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='logo.png', _external=True)}}">
        <h1>CLIENT SHOPPING LIST</h1>
        {% set postcode = request['postcode'] %}
        <h2>POSTCODE: {{ postcode }}</h2>
        <b>REFERENCE #:</b> {{ request['reference_number'] }}
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><b>NAME:</b> {{ request['client_full_name'] }}</td>
                <td colspan="2"><b>CONTACT:</b> {{ request['phone_number'] or '' }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <b>ADDRESS</b><br>
                    {{ request['address_line_1'] }}, {{ postcode }}
                </td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <b>EXTRA INFORMATION</b><br>
                    {{ request['extra_information'] or '' }}
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <b>HOUSEHOLD SIZE:</b> {{ request['household_size'] }}<br>
                    <b>GENDER:</b> {{ request['gender'] }}<br>
                    <b>NUMBER OF ADULTS:</b> {{ request['number_of_adults'] }}<br>
                    <b>NUMBER OF CHILDREN:</b> {{ request['number_of_children'] }}<br>
                    <b>AGE OF CHILDREN:</b> {{ request['age_of_children'] }}
                </td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <b>FEMININE PRODUCTS REQUIRED:</b> {{ request['feminine_products_required'] }}<br>
                    <b>BABY PRODUCTS REQUIRED:</b> {{ request['baby_products_required'] }}<br>
                    <b>PET FOOD REQUIRED:</b> {{ request['pet_food_required'] }}<br>
                    <b>DIETARY REQUIREMENTS:</b> {{ request['dietary_requirements'] }}
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="spacer"><td colspan="4"></td></tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Item Description</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Notes</th>
                <th>Completed?</th>
            </tr>
            {% for item in list["items"] %}
                {% set quantity = item['quantity'] %}
                {% if quantity != "0" %}
            <tr class="compact">
                <td>{{ item['item_description'] }}</td>
                <td>{{ quantity }}</td>
                <td>{{ item['notes'] or '' }}</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
            <tr class="spacer"><td colspan="4"></td></tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4">
                    <b>Warehouse Manager Notes</b><br>
                    {{ list['notes'] }}
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <b>Date Packed</b><br>
                </td>
                <td colspan="3"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <b>Packer Name</b><br>
                </td>
                <td colspan="3"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <b>Packer Signature</b>
                </td>
                <td colspan="3"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried but wasn't able to reproduce. That being said, `page-break-inside` is deprecated and has been replaced with [`break-inside`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/break-inside). Any luck if you try that instead?

Comment: where should i be adding it? inside table? tr? @page? body?

Comment: In this case I would first try `table { break-before: avoid; }` to avoid a page break being inserted immediately before the table.

Comment: I've just realised - this is probably behaviour of the html-to-pdf converter, weasyprint. I have posted an issue on their github; https://github.com/Kozea/WeasyPrint/issues/1134

Comment: I'm new to WeasyPrint myself, but came across this in the docs: _"The break-before, break-after and break-inside properties are supported for pages, but not for columns and regions"_.